# How can I update a tableview cell from a -(void) method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to update a specific dynamic cells font size from a -(void) method or some way without using cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes if you know the exact indexPath to update, or simply you can use `[tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position of the index, as follows:

First create indexPath by row at position:

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0];
```

Then access to cell:

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
[self.view.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[your_index_path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

inside your method. that will cause row update

Comment: Thanks. I am slightly unsure using that code. Where would I put the font size code using that?

Comment: That logic would go wherever you configure your cell either in cellForRowAtIndexPath or in the cell subclass. This method calls cellForRowAtIndexPath again which is how the cell gets updated. Typically by setting a flag on the associated model object before reloading the cell.

Comment: all data, provided for your cell must return form cellForRowForIndexPath. tableview calls this method when it manages to update cell. This code only forces your tableview to reload data

Answer (score 0):

You can not update a cell without having a call to: cellForRowAtIndexPath.
When you want to update font size in a cell, then reload the cell. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method add a conditional statement to check the indexPath of the cell you want a different font size and edit different font size. Do not forget to add else condition so that when the cell reloads it will make the font size normal for other cells.

However if you want somehow. Then you can use global reference variable to the cell. But this will only work if the cell is displaying on screen.
Here is the example code:

```
@interface TableViewController ()
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell;
}
@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row == SPECIFIC_ROW_NUMBER){
        aCell = theCell;
        theCell.tag = SPECIFIC_ROW_NUMBER;
    }else if (theCell.tag == SPECIFIC_ROW_NUMBER){
        // If the cell is dequeued
        aCell = nil;
        theCell.tag = 99999; // some unused row number
    }


}

- (void)someMethod {
    if(theCell != nil){
        aCell.titleLabel.font = NEW_FONT;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Can you give me a bit more info about the last part with the global reference, that sounds great.